# Enviar localização para um WebService em background

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, geolocalização

Como fazer com que minha aplicação IOS usando objective-c envie minha localização em background sem que gaste bateria, e não falhe e não seja reprovado pela Apple, alguém teria ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Sem que gaste bateria é raro, até porque você precisa gastar bateria só para conseguir obter as coordenadas corretas. Em background que você diz é com o aplicativo fechado, ou com ele aberto mas em segundo plano? Se for fechado não é possível, e se for feito, a Apple irá rejeitar!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Lucas Eduardo, em background seria em segundo plano eu vou abrir a aplicação e mas eu não vou fecha-lá, a questão da bateria era de desenvolver uma solução que não gaste muito a bateria do usuário entendeu.

Comment: Se esse é o caso, recomendo essas leituras: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042894/periodic-ios-background-location-updates e http://mobileoop.com/background-location-update-programming-for-ios-7 ;) Lembrando que a bateria vai ser gasta de acordo com a precisão que você escolher, tempo de cada atualização e outros fatores